# Display Created Zones in Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

I seem to be having trouble with one `zone` I created in my `Sphinx Index`.

I did create an entry in the index:

```
index_zones = title,all
```

If I do a ZONE SphinxQL search on title it works fine:

```
Select * from INDEX where MATCH('ZONESPAN:title Red')
```

I get results. However if I do

```
Select * from INDEX where MATCH('ZONESPAN:all Red')
```

I do not.  Yet when I search on those same fields which I likewise indexed as fields they both work. Meaning:

```
Select * from INDEX where MATCH('@(all) Red')
```

Gets results. So there is matching data in the `all` field yet it fails when I try to search on it as a `ZONE`. I have established Zones work since the `title` ZONE works.

I tried using

```
DESCR INDEX
```

Yet that seems to show fields and strings not ZONES. How can I test if somehow the `all` ZONE is in fact indexed as a zone?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think 'all' works as a zone (at least as some sort of 'everything' magic zone) - it would just be indexing content within `<all>` HTML tags :)

`MATCH('ZONESPAN:all Red')` is then matching text between `<all>...</all>` html tags :) - it does not match any text in the rest of the *field*, including the `title` zone

Comment: The term all just used for example it is A-war descriptive field title and is in fact part of HTML text just as title is

Comment: @barryhuntet To confirm that is the exact behavior I am trying to which she do when I re zone all I am looking to search just between the or inside the HTML tag name all. For some reason this works when I search inside the HTML tag name title but not for The tag named 'all'

Comment: ok then. Is perhaps the `html_strip`, stiping the `<all>` tag contents, but not the `<title>` tags?

Comment: I am not sure how to find out if that is the case as I am not sure what sphinx command to run to find out which zones it has identified. Is there some setting besides html_strip=1 I need to look into?

Comment: What is weird to me is as far as I can tell I stripped all html out of the index so not sure how title is found by ZONE:Title. As far as I can tell I'd have had to use `html_index_attrs=title` or any other tagged html I wanted to make sure gets indexed yet somehow it is...

Comment: html_index_attrs would be to include certain HTML attributes in the index, normally stipped. indexing zones happens during stripping, so the title zone can exist, if ultimately stripped from field indexing. What I actully means was <all> content striped by `html_remove_elements` ?

Comment: No I did not use `html_remove_elements`.  The field is more like `record_title` and `record_all` so the index is basically `html_strip = 1` and `index_zones = record_title,record_all`